# How to transform this for loop in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to transform a for loop in a list comprehension but I keep getting a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

The for loop:

```
for item in items:
    if item in default_items.keys():
        total += default_items[item]
```

The list comprehension:

```
[total := total + default_items[item] if item in default_items.keys() for item in items]
```

Here some example of the code in context:

```
items = []
total = 0
default_items = {"tophat": 2, "bowtie": 4, "monocle": 5}
items.append("bowtie")
items.append("jacket")
items.append("monocle")
items.append("chocolate")

for item in items:
    if item in default_items.keys():
        total += default_items[item]
        
print(total) # 9

items = []
total = 0
[total := total + default_items[item] if item in default_items.keys() for item in items] # raising sintax error

print(total) # 9
```

Comment: The `if` should be ***after*** the `for`: `[total := ... for item in items if item ...]`. If you use it like that, it also needs an `else` part

Comment: Also please see [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/6045800). You are not actually building a list, so why are you using ***list***-comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are summing manually in your list comprehension approach, just use `sum`:

```
total = sum(default_items.get(item, 0) for item in items)
```

You also do not need to check if the item is in the default_items dict because `.get(item, 0)` will both get the item if it's available and not affect the sum if it's not.